# проблема с Google admob intersitial ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

Появилась проблема с Google admob interstitial рекламы не показываются вообще весь код написал правильно , как на их официальном сайте написано , и с framework нет проблем . id точный. Вот код :

```
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        if interstitial.isReady {
            print("interstitial admob is ready")
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self.view!.window!.rootViewController)
        }
```

Comment: а с временем загрузки не может быть проблем? я думаю между loadRequest и isReady какое то время пройдет

Comment: Да в этом дело было спасибо огромное , но есть еще одна проблема где тут галочка что ваш ответ точный )

Comment: это не ответ, а комментарий. сейчас перенесу в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего со временем. У вас проверка на готовность рекламы происходит сразу после запроса, скорее всего реклама не успевает загрузиться.

Два решения:

- либо дать приложению какое-то время между loadRequest и isReady.
- либо проверять, что реклама готова к показу через метод делегата [GADInterstitialDelegate](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/protocol_g_a_d_interstitial_delegate-p.html#a98354b092876a675aebde6c98a0edae7)

  ```
  - interstitialDidReceiveAd:
  ```